# buttons are not aligning properly for the Action Bar icon in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using Action Bar in my application and i have a search view and a refresh button. Now the search button padding is getting decreased but the refresh button is not aligning properly. Check the image here:

[image: align buttons]

Now in the menu.xml file, i have added them like below:

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.apps.jobs.alqabas.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_profile"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_profile"
     />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
     />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="Search"
          android:orderInCategory="101"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menuRefresh"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
         android:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

And to change style of the button, I am using this in the style.xml file:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/LoopActionBarButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

 <style name="LoopActionBarButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">30dp</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the padding and min Width?

```
<style name="LoopActionBarButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
            <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dip</item>
            <item name="android:paddingRight">10dip</item>
            <item name="android:minWidth">60dp</item>
        </style>
```

Try this.